# line-height for paragraph spacing not working in Yahoo Mail

Tags: html, email, yahoo-mail

For some reason, line spacing is not working for separating paragraphs, when sending e-mails with this code to my yahoo mail account, or any yahoo mail account.  How can I fix this?

Here's what I'm using, but isn't working:

```
<p style="line-height:150%">
<span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10.5pt; line-height:150%; color:#333333; margin-bottom: 1em;">Caro [Membro],</span>
</p>
<p style="line-height:150%">
<span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10.5pt; line-height:150%; color:#333333; margin-bottom: 1em;">Estou escrevendo com uma atualização importante para os membros de N sobre o Programa de Garantia de Obrigações CDFI.</span>
</p>
```

Looks like this:

[image: line-spacing e-mail problem]

How do I fix this?  Hell, I even put a margin-bottom on it, and that doesn't even seem to work!

Comment: have you tried setting it in px or em?

Comment: What is the equivalent of `150%` in `px` or `em`?  And are you referring to the `line-height` or the `margin-bottom`?

Comment: 1.5em or 15px. not sure how to convert pt to px, though

Comment: @Raffael - I'm trying 1.5 em for the line-height right now, I doubt it will make a difference, but I'm hoping for the best!  Will let you know.

Comment: @Raffael - As I thought, this does not make any difference, still the same results! :(

Comment: does it display correctly in other mail providers?

Comment: @Raffael - Yeah, shows fine in all except Yahoo Mail.

Comment: I'm going to test it using `<div></div>` tags instead of `<p><span></span></p>` hoping this renders better with a `margin-bottom: 1.5em;` and `line-height: 1.5em;`  What are your thoughts on doing this?  You think it is better?

Comment: I don't see a reason why Yahoo should handle ps different than divs. Good luck.

Comment: I've had success with <p style="margin-bottom:1em;">

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you not to use `<p>` in HTML email.  In general I would use `<tr><td>` instead.  Optionally you may wish to use `<br>`, but I don't.

`<p>` varies quite a lot in each web based email/email client, and is much harder to standardise than `<td>`.

To perfectly line up the space between paragraphs, I think the most consistent option is to use a transparent image to control the height of the `<tr><td>`.  It should look something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Lorum Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height=3px"><img src="http://www.example.com/img/3px.png" alt="" height="3px" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lorum Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lorum Ipsum</td>
</tr>
```

3px.png would be a 3px transparent image.  If you create emails often enough you will end up with a collection of heights of transparent pngs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Line Height Setting in your Word Processor.
To fix this problem:

1) Open your Word Processing program.
2) Open your Document.
3) Go to Edit.
4) Go to Select All.
5) Go to Format.
6) Go to Paragraph.
7) Go to Line Spacing
8) Select Proportional
9) Set to 150%
10) Click OK
11) Paste the Text into your Email Program.